# Outbound access in static const arrays

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior

Assume the following code:

```
static const value_string global_variable [] = {
        { 4,   "STRING1" },              
        { 6,   "STRING2" },
        { 9,   "STRING3" },
        { 10,  "STRING4" },
        { 11,  "STRING5" },
        { 12,  "STRING6" },
        { 13,  "STRING7" },
        { 14,  "STRING8" },
        { 15,  "STRING9" },
};

const gchar * try_val_to_str_idx(const guint32 val, const value_string *vs, gint *idx)    
{
   gint i = 0;
   DISSECTOR_ASSERT(idx != NULL); 
   if(vs) {
      while (vs[i].strptr) {
         if (vs[i].value == val) {
            *idx = i;
            return(vs[i].strptr);
         }
         i++;
      }
    }

   *idx = -1;
   return NULL;
}
```

Where `vs` is a static const array (global_variable ), of a structure with two elements:
an `int` and a pointer to a `char`.

This code, is an extract of the wireshark source code. So, this function assumes that vs is a static const variable.

My question is, can I assume that accessing an outbound index of a static const array (that I guess is stored on the .DATA segment) is valid? Is a valid position of memory to access? Or is undefined behavior?

What will happen if I try to find the string relative the value 40, for example?
If it´s valid, how can I be sure, that position of memory will have 0 value, and then `NULL` and exit the while cycle?

Comment: By 'outbound' you mean 'out of bounds'? If so: no, any out of bounds access is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Given the trailing comma in the array declaration, I wonder if some compilers might be creating an array of ten elements, with the last one zero-initialized?  Behavior of such code would be correct if the array contained a sentinel element with a zero pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> *can i assume that accessing an outbound index of a static const array (that i guess is stored on the .DATA segment) is valid?*

Accessing out of bound memory is ***always***  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Do not even *try* doing that.

Comment: That is also my understanding. But i found it strange to find this in wireshark source code, in a function that is widely used. And the truth is, the program never crashes. But if, instead of using a static const, i use heap allocated memory, sometimes the program throws an exception (access memory violation) which i can understand why!

Comment: @nunojsa Well, then that **proves** the program is having UB, isn't it? BTW, did you try debugging the same anytime?

Comment: Yes, it has UB but only when i use dynamic allocated memory. If i use a static const variable, then it never crashes. This is what is bothering me, because i'm well aware that you should not go beyond your array size, or you can get strange things. But in this case, never crashes... that's why i was wondering if there were some differences in .DATA variables.

Comment: @nunojsa Well, that is what the beauty of UB. A segmentation fault is one of the many side effects UB can produce. IMHO, if you get a seg-fault, consider yourself luck that you're being aware of the wrongdoing. Otherwise, God saves!! :)